# Would this this query indicate someone tried to hack my server?

Tags: sql, apache, security

My server crashed today. It is written in node. It's not perfect. The counsel error referred to a line of code that reads and writes to the hard drive based on user names and creates logs. The search should have been formated to look for a txt file named after a user, but the server crashed when it looked for and didn't find `admin.php/ma.txt`.

I don't believe `admin.php` or `ma.txt` would have anything to do with my server or appear in any of my code written in node.js or the program indended to speak to it.

Would `admin.php` or `ma.txt` have any significance to SQL or Apache or somehow indicate someone was trying to snoop around?

Comment: It was probably hit but at least one probe. If you examine your logs regularly, you will find lots of attempts at things like admin.php, which are attempts to probe for known vulnerable web applications (WordPress, PHPMyAdmin, etc). It probably isn't targeted just at you, more likely part of an automated scan looking for vulnerable software.

Comment: thanks mike! info helps alot and i think i see where i when wrong. one of the functions on my server falls to a default when nothing else is specified. i guess i should explain. its an http server but its written in node js. so there is no direct indexing through the url. the url string is interpreted  strictly in a requested / response manner by javascript. so would automated bots have anyway of learning any type of embedded commands i am using in my url string?

Comment: Why have you tagged this "sql"?

Answer (score 0):

Every machine connected to the Internet is subject to continuous, relentless scripted attacks.

Most of those attacks are pretty stupid - they simply try to execute known 
vulnerabilities in common web infrastructure such as web servers, CMS systems, ecommerce solutions etc. The more intelligent scripts look at your web application, and try to find common security problems like SQL injection.

Some scripts are much smarter - they will look for common software development patterns like REST (if I can "GET" a resource, can I "PUT" it?), MVC (if the URL is `/thing/view.html`, is there a `/thing/edit.html`?). So, to answer the question in your comment - it is possible that they will guess your embedded commands.

Most of the time, the scripts aren't targeted at your site in particular - they simply work through long lists of IP addresses, one after the other, day in day out. If they find a weakness, they typically exploit that weakness and inform the person running the script who will then seek to escalate the weakness so they can take advantage.

If your server crashed because someone requested an invalid URL, it may have flagged your system for further investigation by the script owner.

You probably want to read up on Web Application Security - [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) is a good starting point.